# Lily's homework - hackerrank challenge javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Can someone help me solving this challenge? 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lilys-homework/problem

I have tried (see code below) but didn't manage to find a solution...

```
function lilysHomework(arr) {
  console.log(arr)
  let sortedarr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b})
  console.log(sortedarr)
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i] == sortedarr[i]){
      continue
    } else if(arr[i] !== sortedarr[i]){
      for(var j=0; j<arr.length;j++){
        if(arr[i] == sortedarr.indexOf())
      }
    }
  }

}

lilysHomework([1,5,2,4,3]) // 2 swaps
```

Comment: Is this for a job interview?

Comment: Is this for a job interview?

Comment: any help from someone?

Comment: Karim could you have a look?

Answer (score -1):

check my code, it's working fine

```
    'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

// Complete the lilysHomework function below.

function calculate_up(arr){
  var sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b}) ;
  var indexes = {} ;
  for (let [index, value] of arr.entries()){
      indexes[value] = index;
     } 
  var swaps = 0; 
  for (let [right_index, curent_val] of arr.entries()){
      var  right_val = sorted_arr[right_index];
      var  this_index = indexes[right_val];
      if (this_index !== right_index){
         arr[this_index] = curent_val;
         arr[right_index] = right_val;
         indexes[curent_val]= this_index; 
         swaps++; }
  }  return swaps;
}


function calculate_down(arr){
    var sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b}) ;
    sorted_arr.reverse();
    var indexes = {} ;
    for (let [index, value] of arr.entries()){
      indexes[value] = index;
     } 
    
  var swaps = 0; 
  for (let [right_index, curent_val] of arr.entries()){
      var  right_val = sorted_arr[right_index];
      var  this_index = indexes[right_val];
      if (this_index !== right_index){
          arr[this_index] = curent_val;
          arr[right_index] = right_val;
          indexes[curent_val]= this_index; 
          swaps++; }
  }  return swaps; }

function lilysHomework(arr) {
    var arr2=arr.slice();
    var down = calculate_down(arr);
    var up = calculate_up(arr2);
 
 return Math.min(down,up);
}
 

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    const arr = readLine().split(' ').map(arrTemp => parseInt(arrTemp, 10));

    let result = lilysHomework(arr);

    ws.write(result + "\n");

    ws.end();
}
```

Comment: Please limit your code to the necessary part that helps the questioner and explain what is missing or going wrong in their code.